# Error in listing the name of the answerer in the questions tab in my Activity

Tags: bug

[image]

[The name in the above picture](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/26012/blowmamind?tab=questions) is not the name of the person whose answer I accepted. Not a huge bug, just saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not.. It is supposed to show the latest activity. If you click on the **1 day ago** link you will notice the user added another answer. Check [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/49340/why-is-scientism-philosophically-wrong/49410#49410).

It is not a bug.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I am such an idiot. Didn't even check all my Activity on the other sites.

Comment: meh.. we all have our oops moments